# Help with upgrading to Tails 1.1

Tags: tails, update

I have the previous version of Tails and have been trying to upgrade to Tails 1.1 Nothing I've tried so far works. I'm not savvy with CMD terminals so go easy on me. I tried using Tails installer to clone and upgrade to a different flash drive, but once the cloning and upgrading are complete, my computer won't boot from the new flash. I tried downloading Tails 1.1 from pirates bay and signature doesn't match. please help.

Comment: Do not ever download tails from other sources then the official website.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to upgrade is: download a Tails 1.1 ISO, verify it, and burn it to a DVD. Boot on the DVD, then use the Tails Installer to upgrade your USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

The [release notes from Tails 1.1](https://tails.boum.org/news/version_1.1/) have a section on [upgrading](https://tails.boum.org/news/version_1.1/index.en.html#index5h1). I try to describe the process below. If there are questions left please have a look at the original document or add them as comment.

1. Start your CD/DVD or USB stick.
2. Set a password for administration. When you start Tails you'll see the *Welcome to Tails* window. In this case you want *more options*, so click `Yes`. Now you'll see a section called *Administration password*. Enter your password into the two boxes.
   Another way to set the password is to use the shell. Open a root shell ( Applications > Accessories > Root Terminal) and enter `sudo -i`.
3. Within the root terminal you enter the following commands:
   `echo "deb http://deb.tails.boum.org/ 1.1 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tails-upgrade.list` -- This writes the line starting with `deb` into the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tails-upgrade.list`. You can also open an editor and insert the string `deb http://deb.tails.boum.org/ 1.1 main` into the file. The next steps updates the package archives and installs the package `liveusb-creator`. Just enter this line into the root terminal:
   `apt-get update && apt-get install liveusb-creator`
4. When the above is finished start the *Tails Installer* (Applications > Tails > Tails Installer) and select *Upgrade from ISO*.
5. Insert the device you want to upgrade and choose the device from *Target Device*.
6. Choose the ISO after clicking Browse and select `Yes`.
7. Finish.